# Fitnesse Wiki markup escape "Error"

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

I am using Fitnesse with C# and FitSharp.

My test wants to test for the string "Error" being returned. However this is being interpreted as the "Error" keyword, and the test fails.

How can I tell Fitnesse to treat this as a string?

```
Example markup...

!|GetReasonFixture|
|Reason           |
|Error            |
#|{{{Error}}}     |  <--- this doesn't work
#|!-Error-!       |  <--- neither does this
#|${MyVar}        |  <--- nope
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing for an error is one of the standard compare operators in fitsharp (see http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/CellOperators.html) you should be able to remove it using wiki syntax below

|configure|processor|remove operator|My.Operator|

and add it back in if needed later in the page using

|configure|processor|add operator|My.Operator|

|configure|processor|add operator first|My.Important.Operator|

or via code as

```
Processor.RemoveOperator("My.Operator")
Processor.AddOperator("My.Operator")
Processor.AddOperatorFirst("My.Important.Operator")
```

or alternatively you can add or remove operators in the suite config file

```
<suiteConfig>
    <Fit.Operators>
        <Remove>My.Operator</Remove>
        <Add>My.Operator</Add>
        <AddFirst>My.Important.Operator</AddFirst>
    </Fit.Operators>
</suiteConfig>
```